# Javascript: Check if string contains only letters, numbers, whitespace, and specific symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to do a string validation, the rule is the string only allowed to have the following characters:

- Letters
- Numbers
- Space or Whitespace
- Specific symbols : ( ) . - /

If the string contains a character that is not in the above list, it should return a false result

I tried to do it like this:

```
return value.match(/[().-\/]/) || value.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]+$") || (value.indexOf(' ') !== -1) ? true : false;
```

It works if you have only disallowed character, if I have allowed characters mixed in it will return true

Comment: `^[-A-Za-z0-9().\/ ]+$`

Comment: @VishalSingh you wasted an answer here xD also Newts you should accept Huskell's solution.

Comment: @GottZ His regex is cleaner than mine haha. Probably good to change the space for `\s` that considers a few different whitespace characters as well.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raJcug_vW0c that's a fun one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
// test if string contains something that is not: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, whitespaces and symbols :)./(-
const conditionRegex = /([^a-zA-Z0-9:\.\/\(\)\-\s])/g;
return conditionRegex.test(anotherString);
```

Not sure if you want to check if contains or not any different character, but you just need to invert if that is the case. The example I wrote will return `true` if something different is typed.

PS: to invert just remove the `^` at the start like this: `/([a-zA-Z0-9:\.\/\(\)\-\s])/g`

Comment: Hm. Thinking about it.. I'm not sure if you can use `-` if it's not in the beginning

Comment: Oh it works. Interesting.. Where did I encounter this problem before.. Maybe from not escaping it… Well. Putting it in front doesn't require escaping so it's one character less :)